# How to access dictionary value in jinja? Is it possible or not? If possible then how?

Tags: dictionary, jinja2, show

I'm trying to use this code snippet in a Django project.
How can I access each key's value (the list)?
And show the list items?

I want to display a table like this using Jinja.
Is it possible?

| key | values |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1,2 |
| 200 | 3,4 |
| 300 | 5,6 |
| 400 | 7,8 |

There can be thousands of rows in the table.

```py
def index(request):

    data = {
        100: [{'childId': 1, 'childStructure': 'Leaf'}, {'childId': 2, 'childStructure': 'Intermediate'}],
        200: [{'childId': 3, 'childStructure': 'Intermediate'}, {'childId': 4, 'childStructure': 'Leaf'}],
        300: [{'childId': 5, 'childStructure': 'Leaf'}, {'childId': 6, 'childStructure': 'Intermediate'}],
        400: [{'childId': 7, 'childStructure': 'Intermediate'}, {'childId': 8, 'childStructure': 'Leaf'}],
    }

    return render(request,'index.html', {'data': data})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a for to loop on dictionaries. You just have to use `dict.items()` to do so, [as pointed in the documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#for).

Given the template:

```html
<table style="border: 1px solid">
  <tr>
    <th>key</th>
    <th>value</th>
  </tr>
{% for key, value in data.items %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ key }}</td>
    <td>{{ value | map(attribute='childId') | join(',') }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

This would give you:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>key</th>
    <th>value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>1,2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>3,4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>300</td>
    <td>5,6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>400</td>
    <td>7,8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: unfortunately it shows: `Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'data.items()'`

Comment: Yes, without the `()` in Django, indeed: `{% for key, value in data.items %}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to acces an specific item, you can do something like this

```
{{data[100].childId if 100 in data else -1}}
```